# Cycle through input fields

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a table which I'm populating with some data I get from a database query

[Table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muowa.png)

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in reservasTable">
    <td> {{row.L}} </td>
    <td> {{row.number}} </td>
    <td> {{row.line}} </td>
    <td> {{row.cod_art}} </td>
    <td> {{row.creation_date}} </td>
    <td> {{row.deadline}} </td>
    <td> {{row.qtt_ordered}} </td>
    <td> {{row.qtt_delivered}} </td>
    <td> {{row.ocor}} </td>
    <td> <input type="text" id="qttField" ng-model-onblur ng-model="qtt" ui-keypress="{13:'setQtt($event)'}">
</tr>
```

The only field I don't get from the JSON query is the last one, an input field which is used to fill with a certain amount (Quantity).

What I need to do is: after I fill whatever fields I want, (e.g., the 1st, 4rd and last) I need to **cycle through those fields**, **check which ones are filled** and **get the value** from them.

I can't seem to get the value just from the model, since the model is the same for every field, that's why I'm currently using the 'Enter' button to update the value and send it to an array:

**Simple Version:**

```
$scope.arrayQtt = [];
var i = 0;
$scope.setQtt = function(evt){
   $scope.arrayQtt[i] = evt.srcElement.value;
   i++;
};
```

It is preferable to check all input fields with a 'Confirmation' button, after all fields are filled, since an user can edit a field the amount of times he wants before clicking the 'Confirmation' button.

Any help, advice or guidance is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why don't you change your ngModel to "row.qtt" ? Every row that user entered a quantity will have that property, and you can simply check for it and do whatever you want.

Comment: Well, sometimes I'm dumb enough to try 50 different solutions than the easiest one. I've tried that in the past but I wasn't treating it properly after getting the value, I got it to work now. Thanks mate, nice catch ;) . Take care!